# telerik grid Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'i.validator' is null or not an object error on editing

Tags: telerik, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

I have upgraded MVC extensions to MVC Q3 2011(version 2011.3.1115.340). I have a telerik grid using ajax editing inline mode. Grid displays correctly but when I try to edit a row, it gives
Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'i.validator' is null or not an object  in telerik.grid.editing.min.js file. Below is my code:

```
 <div id="addEditSelectionTable">
  <% Html.Telerik().Grid(Model.InnerModel.SelectionsList)
            .Name("Grid")
            .ToolBar(commands => commands.Insert())
            .DataKeys(keys => keys.Add(o => o.SelectionID))
            .DataBinding(dataBinding =>
             {
                 dataBinding.Ajax()
                     .Select("_SelectAjaxEditing", "Grid")
                     .Insert("_InsertAjaxEditing", "Grid")
                     .Update("_SaveAjaxEditing", "Grid")
                     .Delete("_DeleteAjaxEditing", "Grid");
             })
            .Columns(columns =>
            {
                columns.Bound(o => o.SelectionID);
                columns.Bound(o => o.Enabled);
                columns.Bound(o => o.SelectionType);
                columns.Bound(o => o.Frequency);
                   columns.Command(commands =>
                     {
                        commands.Edit();
                        commands.Delete();
                      }).Width(200);
            })
            .Scrollable(s => s.Enabled(true))
            .Scrollable(scrolling => scrolling.Height(500))
            .Resizable(resize => resize.Columns(true))
            .Reorderable(reorder => reorder.Columns(true))
            .Footer(false)
            .Render();
%>
 </div>
```

My controller has GridAction :

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    [GridAction]
    public ActionResult _SaveAjaxEditing(int id)
    {
        var sModel = SamplesModel.GetAllSampleSelections();
        return View(new GridModel(sModel.SelectionsList));
    }
```

No clue why this might be hapening. grid works fine without editing.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. The cause of mine is that my editable grid is on a modal dialog, and I think Telerik does not create the validator object when rendering a grid on a dialog rather than on a normal page.

I also had a non-editable grid on the main page that triggers the dialog. What I did is to append the "Editable(editing => editing.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine)" attribute to the main grid to pretend it is editable (but without rendering any command buttons). This way, the sub-grid on the dialog will use the validator object created for the main grid.

Hope it helps.